Infinitesimal generator
From Conformal field theory (Di Francesco, Pierre Mathieu):

We now study the effect of infinitesimal transformations on the action. Such transformations may in general be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{\prime \mu} & =x^\mu+\omega_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \omega_a} \\
\Phi^{\prime}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime}\right) & =\Phi(\boldsymbol{x})+\omega_a \frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \omega_a}(\boldsymbol{x}).
\end{aligned}\tag{2.125}
$$
Here $\left\{\omega_a\right\}$ is a set of infinitesimal parameters, which we shall keep to first order only. It is customary to define the generator $G_a$ of a symmetry transformation by the following expression for the infinitesimal transformation at a same point:
$$
\delta_\omega \Phi(x) \equiv \Phi^{\prime}(x)-\Phi(x) \equiv-i \omega_a G_a \Phi(x).\tag{2.126}
$$
We may relate this definition to Eq. (2.125) by noting that, to first order in $\omega_a$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi^{\prime}\left(x^{\prime}\right) & =\Phi(x)+\omega_a \frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \omega_a}(x) \\
& =\Phi\left(x^{\prime}\right)-\omega_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \omega_a} \partial_\mu \Phi\left(x^{\prime}\right)+\omega_a \frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \omega_a}\left(x^{\prime}\right).
\end{aligned}\tag{2.127}
$$
The explicit expression for the generator is therefore
$$
i G_a \Phi=\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \omega_a} \partial_\mu \Phi-\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \omega_a}.\tag{2.128}
$$

$\textbf{Question}$: Generators of the conformal group are written:
$\begin{aligned} & P_\mu=-i \partial_\mu \\ & L_{\mu \nu}=i\left(x_\mu \partial_\nu-x_\nu \partial_\mu\right) \\ & D=-i x^\mu \partial_\mu \\ & K_\mu=-i\left(2 x_\mu x^\nu \partial_\nu-x^2 \partial_\mu\right)\end{aligned}$
This is true if $\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \omega_a}=0$ but why is this the case?

For example, with dilatation, $x^{'\mu}=e^ax^\mu \approx x^\mu + ax^\mu$. So $\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta a}=x^\mu$. So $iG_a\phi = x^\mu\partial_\mu \phi \rightarrow G_a = - i x^\mu\partial_\mu$ and there is no additional contribution from a change in the field

When you wrote the generators as differential operators, this was just the orbital part. The term you dropped was the spin part. Consider a primary operator with spin 0 and scaling dimension $\Delta$. Its transformation law under dilations is
\begin{align}
e^{iD} \phi(x) e^{-iD} \equiv \phi'(x) = \lambda^\Delta \phi(\lambda x).
\end{align}
If you write $\lambda = 1 + i \epsilon$, the left hand side yields $[D, \phi(x)]$ by BCH while the right hand side expands to
\begin{align}
(1 + i \epsilon)^\Delta \phi((1 + i \epsilon) x) = \phi(x) + i \epsilon x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi(x) + i \epsilon \Delta \phi(x).
\end{align}
So we see the differential operator you wrote plus something proportional to $\Delta$ which should also be there.
