Generator of symmetry
In this definition, of the generator $G_a$ of a symmetry:
$$
i G_a \Phi=\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \omega_a} \partial_\mu \Phi-\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \omega_a}
$$
Where $\mathcal{F}(\phi)=\phi'(x')$.
When is $\mathcal{F}=0$?
For example, if we want to find the generators of the conformal group.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/829231/2451
